# Feedback on why constantly draining. It's starting to flood backyard

Tags: water-heater

There's no leakage near/ around water heater. No slime or build up of any kind.
But there's constant hot water drainage coming out through pipe in backyard. It's starting to flood back porch area.
It's cream colored pipe coming out of wall of house.
Paper work says it's a gas fired water heater.
Any tips?

Comment: That might be the condensation drain if that is a gas water heater of the condensing type. If that is so and you have high gas usage there might be a problem with the thermostat resulting the heater running continuously.

Answer (score 2):

Water heaters have a safety device called a T & P valve, T is Temperature, P is for pressure. it sits atop or near the top of the unit and is designed to "pop off" or open in cases where the temperature or pressure is high.These can go bad by themselves or after being bled by a well meaning or curious person.
See if the temperature setting is maxed out, if so lower it some that may help, otherwise replace the T & P valve.